Read firmware from Teensy 3.2
I have an old application where a Teensy 3.2 is used
Now the module has been damaged, and I would like to buy a new Teensy 3.2 module and copy the firmware to it by reading it from the old module.
The problem is that the Teensy Loader tool seems like it can only write firmware but not read it. So the question is: is there a way to read the firmware from an already programmed Teensy 3.2 and transfer it to a new one? Maybe even using NXP/Freescale tools.
Can anyone help me?

You can read the flash memory where the firmware is stored if you connect to the MCU via JTAG if flash security is disabled. This pdf from the NXP community forums describes the process using NXPs MCUXpresso IDE. You would also need a debug probe like MCU-Link that you have to connect to the JTAG interface.
I'm not familiar with these Teensy boards, but looking at the schematic the JTAG pins (PTA0-PTA3) of the main Kinetis K20 MCU (U1) are connected to a different MCU (U2) that acts as a bootloader. So you would have to disable that MCU somehow (by cutting the traces for example).

(Source: pjrc.com)
If you do this successfully, you basically get a HEX dump of the firmware. This probably won't be compatible with the Teensy Loader tool.
So while it might be possible, it would be easier to ask the manufacturer of the Teensy boards first if there is an easier way using their tools. You should also ask if flash security is enabled, because if it is you're out of luck.

I asked the board manufacturer and there seems to be no way to extract the FW with their toolchain

@FedericoMassimi Did you ask about flash security?

No, they couldn't answer me. but it is an evaluation board, it is not a product, so it would not make sense to have activated this option.
